# Scala import inside or outside class - performance consideration with implicits

Tags: scala

In scala you can use `import` statement at the top of the file (like in `Java`) and for example inside a class.

My question is - does it make a difference -- in terms of *compile times*, not run-time performance -- which way I use it? I suspect that if we don't have any implicit conversions there won't be any difference (like in `Java`) but how does it look if we import implicits?

Are they somehow indexed by compiler or looked up on demand when they are needed so it won't matter if I will do `import` statements that have some `implicit def`s?